# Permission denied (publickey) when SSH Access to Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I want to use my Amazon ec2 instance but faced the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have created my key pair and downloaded **.pem** file.

Given:

```
chmod  600 pem file.
```

Then, this command

```
ssh -i /home/kashif/serverkey.pem  ubuntu@ec2-54-227-242-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

But have this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Also, **how can I connect with filezilla to upload/download files?**

Comment: regarding your 2nd question, connect with filezilla to upload/download files, check this out for step by step instructions - http://y2u.be/e9BDvg42-JI

Comment: are you sure you did not use "sudo chmod 600 pem file" this would cause this error and mean that you would need to use sudo before ssh

Comment: Also for some Debian OS the username is `admin`. At least for 6.5 and 7.0 versions.

Comment: You actually want read-access only on your instance key: `chmod 400 private.pem`

Comment: If your username is `ec2-user`, make sure you're not using `ec2_user` :)

Comment: Make sure the **user** as which you're trying to connect has the key listed in *his/her* `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: What does your **sshd_config** look like?  You may have needed to add `PermitRootLogin without-password                                                                                 
PasswordAuthentication yes` to it.

Comment: I have mistakenly deleted .ssh/authorized_keys files how can I log in again?

Comment: If AWS EC2 instance is set properly, there will be no restrictions inside ubuntu directory, read/write to home director will have Permission restrictions.

Answer (score 588, accepted):

This error message means you failed to authenticate.

These are common reasons that can cause that:

1. Trying to connect with the wrong key. Are you sure this instance is using this keypair?
2. Trying to connect with the wrong username. `ubuntu` is the username for the ubuntu based AWS distribution, but on some others it's `ec2-user` (or `admin` on some Debians, according to Bogdan Kulbida's answer)(can also be `root`, `fedora`, see below)
3. Trying to connect the wrong host. Is that the right host you are trying to log in to?

Note that `1.` will also happen if you have messed up the `/home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on your EC2 instance.

About `2.`, the information about which username you should use is often lacking from the AMI Image description. But you can find some in AWS EC2 documentation, bullet point `4.` : 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

> Use the ssh command to connect to the instance. You'll specify the private key (.pem) file and user_name@public_dns_name. For Amazon Linux, the user name is ec2-user. For RHEL5, the user name is either root or **ec2-user**. For Ubuntu, the user name is **ubuntu**. For Fedora, the user name is either **fedora** or **ec2-user**. For SUSE Linux, the user name is **root**. Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with your AMI provider.

**Finally**, be aware that there are many other reasons why authentication would fail. SSH is usually pretty explicit about what went wrong if you care to add the `-v` option to your SSH command and read the output, as explained in many other answers to this question.

Comment: I have deleted one previous key. Now i create another. But in istance description he is displaying that this instance is using "wer'hare" key. While i have delete this key. And create "new-keys". How instance can use new key.

Comment: While i have reading if you have lost key that you generate on instance creation. Then you can create another to access your instance.

Comment: Well, you should never delete a key in use because the only way for you to access the machine is with this key, so you cannot add a new key in the authorizedkeys file without the old one.

Comment: I don't think the interface offers you to add a key to a running instance so you will have to start a new one if you have lost the key to your running instance.

Comment: This answer solved it for me. The default username for this instance was "ubuntu", not ec2-user as it said in the AWS manual. Try using 'ec2-user@_your_EC2_IP.amazonaws.com

Comment: +1 ec2-user solved it

Comment: Regarding #1, wrong key, adding -v (verbose) to the ssh command line showed me which keys it was trying and that led me to realize it wasn't trying the key I had generated because I had named it something other than id_rsa or id_dsa.

Comment: `chmod` can also cause this. I accidentally changed permissions to `root` on my `ec2-user` folder. Lol.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an edit for this, but I think a user not having access to his home directory rare enough and maybe not the main reason why one gets the "permission denied (public key)" error.

Comment: ec2-user worked for me, but how do we find out the username of instance?

Comment: @Raj I think that information is lacking in the Image description. You can otherwise find it in AWS documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html at bullet point 4. "[...] You'll specify the private key (.pem) file and user_name@public_dns_name. For Amazon Linux, the user name is ec2-user. For RHEL5, the user name is either root or ec2-user. For Ubuntu, the user name is ubuntu. For Fedora, the user name is either fedora or ec2-user. For SUSE Linux, the user name is root. Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with your AMI provider."

Comment: I accidentally deleted /home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys is there any way to fix this? i need at least download all the files to make a backup...

Comment: There's no way you can connect to your instance, that's security. But you can take an image of your instance and start a new one with the "same" EBS and a new key.

Comment: "ubuntu is the username for the ubuntu based AWS distribution," This is what got me. Was used to ec2-user, just assumed that was always the username.

Comment: Can you please help me out with the following question posted by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806657

Comment: Just wanted to second (or third, or fourth...) the fact I did not know `ec2-user` was *not* the default username on the Ubuntu EC2 servers.

Comment: Three years later they still haven't made this clear enough... But since then I discovered Azure's documentation and I still think AWS is much better documented.

Comment: #2 fixed mine, AWS should really have this properly documented in their instance page. Thanks

Comment: You also need make sure that the authorized_keys file has the correct permission, i.e 644. That's what fixed this issue for me

Comment: `/home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file solved my problem. Just copy and paste your (own laptop's) SSH key to server, in this file.

Comment: For me it was a `.pem` file with the correct name but somehow didn't work. After re-downloading the key file and replacing it in `~/.ssh` it worked

Answer (score 48):

In this case the problem arises from lost Key Pair. About this:

- **There's no way to change Key Pair on an instance**. You have to create a new instance that uses a new Key Pair.
- **You can work around the problem** if your instance is used by an application on **Elastic Beanstalk**.

You can follow these steps:

1. Access to **AWS Management Console**
2. Open **Elastic Beanstalk** Tab
3. Select your application from **All Applications** Tab
4. From left side menù select **Configuration**
5. Click on the **Instances** Gear
6. In **Server** Form check the **EC2 Key Pair** input and select your new Key Pair. You may have to **refresh** the list in order to see a new Key Pair you're just created.
7. **Save**
8. Elastic Beanstalk will create for you new instances associated with the new key pair.

---

In general, remember you have to allow your EC2 instance to accept inbound SSH traffic.

To do this, you have to create a specific rule for the Security Group of your EC2 instance.
You can follow these steps.

1. Access to **AWS Management Console**
2. Open **EC2 Tab**
3. From **Instances** list select the instance you are interested in
4. In the **Description Tab** chek the name of the **Security Group** your instance is using.
5. Again in **Description Tab** click on **View rules** and check if your Security Group has a rule for inbound ssh traffic on port 22
6. If not, in **Network & Security** menù select **Security Group**
7. Select the **Security Group** used by your instance and the click **Inbound Tab**
8. On the left of Inbound Tab you can compose a rule for SSH inbound traffic:

   - **Create a new rule**: SSH
   - **Source**: *IP address* or *subnetwork* from which you want access to instance
   - **Note**: If you want grant *unlimited access* to your instance you can specify *0.0.0.0/0*, although Amazon not recommend this practice
9. Click **Add Rule** and then **Apply Your Changes**
10. Check if you're now able to connect to your instance via SSH.

Hope this can help someone as helped me.

Comment: The second part of your answer is wrong. You cannot get "Permission denied (publickey)." if you haven't correctly set the firewall settings (Security Groups). "Permission denied (publickey)." is an error message from SSH and is a proof that your Security Groups configuration is right. Instead, you would get "ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused"

Comment: Long story short: The error message tells that this issue has nothing to do with your Security Groups configuration.

Comment: You're right. The second part treats another kind of problem. I fixed the post.

Comment: If you lost the key I think a possible way to solve it would be to take a snapshot of the instance and then start a new one with a new key. In that case Amazon appends the new public key in .ssh/authorized_keys so make sure to remove the old one afterwards. (and be careful not to remove the new one or you're back to your first issue)

Answer (score 43):

This is how I solved the problem

```
ssh -i <key> ec2-user@<ec2 ip>
```

Comment: It seemed the key for me here was the DNS address of the host vs IP. ec2-user@<ip> worked for me.

Comment: Solution as well.

Answer (score 26):

I solved the problem just putting `sudo` before

```
sudo ssh -i mykey.pem myec2.amazonaws.com
```

But the proper solution is to change the ownership first, and then connect as a normal user as Janus Troelsen said below. In my case it would be:

```
chown wellington:wellington key.pem
```

Comment: Worked for me (had to update some packages after though)!

Comment: the proper solution is to change the ownership first, and then connect as a normal user. use `sudo chown wellington:wellington key.pem`.

Comment: it is working, in your case because you are trying to login that VM at Amazon which support **root** user

Comment: I had done whoami then sudo chown user_name_given_by_whoami xxxx.pem

Answer (score 23):

Try using

```
sudo ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@<ec2_ip_public_dns>
```

OR

```
sudo ssh -i mykey.pem ec2-user@<ec2_ip_public_dns>
```

Answer (score 22):

Another possible cause of this error:

When user's **home directory is group writeable**, the user cannot login.

(Reproduced on Ubuntu instance.)

Comment: +1 Wish I had read this 4 hours ago!!! Solved my issue where rsync -a was overwriting the permission of my ec2-user folder.

Comment: After I mv my home directory, I couldn't login.

Comment: So how do you login on a machine that's thus affected, and you cannot login to it at all?

Comment: Fix permissions on /home directory works for me too, thanks! @AlexPetralia, your link is broken =/ but has a post in aws forum talking about this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=334402

Comment: Can someone like Alex Petralia or @Michael Hobbs repost (or restate) the solution to this?

Comment: @JakubLangr chmod 755 on the users home directory

Comment: Can you please help me out with the following question posted by me stackoverflow.com/questions/39806657

Answer (score 7):

for the ubuntu 12.04 lts micro instance i had to set the user name as option

```
ssh -i pemfile.pem -l ubuntu dns
```

Comment: this worked for me, i'm surprised it is not part of the aws documentation to actually discuss users that may be required.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do the following steps:

1. Open your ssh client or terminal if you are using Linux.
2. Locate your private key file and change your directory. 
       `cd <path to your .pem file>`
3. Execute below commands:
   `chmod 400 <filename>.pem` 
   `ssh -i <filename>.pem ubuntu@<ipaddress.com>`

If `ubuntu` user is not working then try with `ec2-user`.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with the same permission denied error apparently due to

```
key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
```

In my situation the cause was the ssh config file of the current user (~/.ssh/config).

Using the following:

```
ssh -i ~/myKey.pem ec2-user@<IP address> -v 'exit'
```

The initial output showed:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ec2-user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ec2-user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

...  many debug lines cut here ...

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/somekey.pem
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

The third line above is where the problem actual was identified; however, I looked for at the debug message four lines from the bottom (above) and was misled. There isn't a problem with the key but I tested it and compared other configurations.

My user ssh config file reset the host via an unintended global setting as shown below. The first Host line should not have been a comment.

```
$ cat config
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
#Host myAlias
        user ec2-user
        Hostname bitbucket.org
#        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/somekey
#        IdentitiesOnly yes

Host my2ndAlias
        user myOtherUser
        Hostname bitbucket.org
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my2ndKey
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I hope someone else finds this helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I forgot to add the username (ubuntu) when connecting my Ubuntu instance. So I tried this:

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-ec2-instance.amazonaws.com
```

and the correct way was

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ubuntu@my-ec2-instance.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Legit beginner error. If you forget to add the username, then it will use the username of user you are logged in with in your local computer.

Answer (score 3):

This has happened to me multiple times. I have used Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.2 and Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS which are both on the free tier.

Every time I have launched an instance I have permission denied show up. I haven't verified this but my theory is that the server is not completely set up before I try to ssh into it. After a few tries with permission denied, I wait a few minutes and then I am able to connect. If you are having this problem I suggest waiting five minutes and trying again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible frustrating scenarios that produces this error:

If you are lunching a new instance from an AMI you created of another instance (say instance xyz), then the new instance will only accept the same key that instance A used. This is totally understandable but it gets confusing because during the step by step process of creating the new instance, you are asked to select or create a key (at the very last step) which will not work.

Regardless of the key you create or select, only the key you were using for instance XYZ will will be accepted by the new instance.

Comment: It usually appends the new public key to the authorized_keys file, hence making both usable. It's been a while since I tested though, but that's what I would expect to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a while too until I found the following:

```
eb ssh
```

When you use that from the project directory, bingo-bango no muss no fuss, you're in

Answer (score 2):

In my own case, i did the following:

```
chmod 400 <key.pem>

ssh -i <key.pem> ec2-user@ec2_public_dns (for debian)
```

I was initially using `root@` part and i got this prompt:

```
Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm in Windows with *[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)*. It works great on both File Explorer and PuTTY SSH Shell to access my Amazon [EC2-VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235022/4058484) Linux. There is nothing to do with `chmod pem file` as it uses `myfile.ppk` [converted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html#putty-private-key) by [*PuTTYgen*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen) from the *pem file*.

Answer (score 2):

same thing happened to me, but all that was happening is that the private key got lost from the keychain on my local machine.

> ssh-add -K

re-added the key, then the ssh command to connect returned to work.

Comment: It happens every single time after restart and i need to re-run above command any workaround for this.

Comment: haven't verified this myself, but the verified answer here might help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by login into Ubuntu box using below command:

```
ssh -i ec2key.pem ubuntu@ec2-public-IP
```

Comment: Please Give some details.

Answer (score 1):

I've twice had keys and ssh command line correct (I know because I'm duplicating a working Ubuntu 14.04 instance), but just not been able to ssh into a new instance, even after waiting 5 minutes as suggested by Wade Anderson above.

I had to destroy and re-create the machine.  This has happened on two separate occasions.  Since I can't get in initially, I can't see what's wrong.

So, if you have this problem, try that.

Answer (score 1):

you must check these few things:

1. Make sure your IP address is correct
2. Make sure you are using the correct Key
3. Make sure you are using the correct username, you can try:
   3.1. admin
   3.2. ec2-user
   3.3. ubuntu

I had the same problem, and it solved after I changed username to ubuntu. In AWS documentation was mentioned to user ec2-user but somehow does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

My private key was set to permission `400` and was resulting in Permission denied setting it to '644' helped me .

**key_load_private_type: Permission denied** is the specific error I was getting

**Solution:**
`Sudo chmod 644 <key.pem>`

Note: set to 644 is must, it was not working with 400

Answer (score 1):

When you try doing

`ssh -i <.pem path> root@ec2-public-dns`

You get a message advising you to use the `ec2-user`.

`Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".`

So use

`ssh -i <.pem path> ec2-user@ec2-public-dns`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and its very strange. If you believe you are doing all good than follow this:
Some times there is confusion about user for the EC2 instance!! Some times you get ec2-user, ubuntu, centos etc. So check your username for the machie!!

**Login with root user**

`ssh -i yourkey.pem (400 permission) root@<ip>`

**It will throw error and will give you the available username**. then login with that user.

Answer (score 1):

It's a basic thing, but always confirm which user you are trying to do the login. Im my case **was just a distraction**. I was trying using a **root** user:

```
ssh -i ~/keys/<key_name> root@111.111.111.111
```

But was **another user**:

```
ssh -i ~/keys/<key_name> dedeco@111.111.111.111
```

Answer (score 1):

i had same error but different situation. to me it happened out of the blue after a lot of time i could ssh successfully to my remote computer out there. after a lot of searching the solution to my problem were file permissions. it is strange of course because i didn't change any permissions in my computer or the remote one belonging to the ssh's files/directories. so from the good [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Key_ignored_by_the_server) here it is:

For the local machine do this:

```
$ chmod 700 ~/
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```

For the remote machine do that:

```
$ chmod 700 ~/
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

after that my ssh started to working again without the permission denied (publickey) thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another Possible Issue: Wrong login ID

Check 'Usage Instructions'

All good suggestions above, but what I ran into was that I selected a pre-made instance. After the instance has started , look at the usage instructions. I incorrectly used login id of the private key when in the instructions I was supposed to use 'bitnami' (e.g. bitnami@domain -i key.pem)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: xxxx.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

My problem was that the instance did not start properly due to error on the run-on-start-up script from `Step 3: Configure instance detail` under `Advanced details:`

What I thought I entered:

`#include 
https://xxxx/bootstrap.sh`

What actually entered breaks the instance setup

`#include`

`https://xxxx/bootstrap.sh`

So the public key on instance side was not created

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive.

Wrong   : SSH **EC2-user**@XXX.XX.XX.XX -i MyEC2KeyPair.pem

Correct : SSH **ec2-user**@XXX.XX.XX.XX -i MyEC2KeyPair.pem

Answer (score -1):

I was able to SSH from one machine, but not from another. Turns out I was using the wrong private key.

The way I figured this out was by getting the public key from my private key, like this:

`ssh-keygen -y -f ./myprivatekey.pem`

What came out didn't match what was in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score -1):

All of the top ranked answers above are accurate and should work for most cases. In the event that they don't as was in my case, I simply got rid of my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on the machine I was trying to ssh from and that solved the problem for me. I was able to connect afterwards.

Comment: While deleting `known_hosts` can solve a problem when connecting to server that has changed its host key (while it's a bad approach anyway), I'm pretty sure it cannot solve *"Permission denied (publickey)"* error.