# Try to check my connection publickey error (beanstalk ssh keys)

Tags: git, ssh, public-key, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'll do my first steps with Git. I have a beanstalk-account as well. My IDE is phpstorm.

I installed it on my Mac via the installer => /usr/local/git was installed successfully.
After that I generate a ssh key and copied in my beanstalk account.
[Here's the tutorial](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-mac.html#installing-git).

```
The authenticity of host 'myaccount.beanstalkapp.com (204.232.132.2)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 30:9a:97:f3:19:4f:d1:6e:28:76:9e:e7:d1:df:2c:31.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I typed 'yes' and then ..

```
Warning: Permanently added 'myaccount.beanstalkapp.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

My public key is in the same folder .ssh/beanstalk.pub

What's my problem?

I try to clone my repository in phpStorm:

```
git@myaccount.beanstalkapp.com:/phpstorm_git.git
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Would `git@myaccount.beanstalkapp.com/phpstorm_git.git` work better? (without the '`:`')

Comment: Try `ssh -v git@myaccount.beanstalkapp.com` to check if it is problem with SSH connection, or path to your repository.

Comment: Check if 'myaccount.beanstalkapp.com' got added to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`... the "Permission denied (publickey)." message is strange here.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for others landing in the same situation. I had the same issues and this post helped me solve it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537879/3847469

Basically, I had allowed SSH traffic but my beanstalk instance was not associated with the keypair I had generated. The above post describes how to do that. I was able to login after that.

Answer (score 0):

You simply type yes and press ENTER, which will add your account's hostname accountname.beanstalkapp.com to a known_hosts file, however as it's eding the known_hosts file in ~/.ssh you will need sudo permissions so just use: `sudo git@myaccount.beanstalkapp.com:/phpstorm_git.git`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just your host is wrong, into this file, and check you host

`~/.ssh/known_hosts`

[Permission denied (publickey) when SSH Access to Amazon EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551556)

Comment: Answers are more valuable when you summarize what is being linked. Especially in the case when links die.