# couldn't get root access to aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to access aws instance using ssh with private keys downloaded from aws.

I got access using `ec2-user` which their documentation suggested.

`$ ssh -i upd_prayag.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-209-155-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Apparently, I find two users there, 

`ec2-user
prayagupd`

What I want is `ls` the user `prayagupd` to check whether the directory I have cloned from `github` exists there.

Unfortunately I see `permission denied` message on that user.

I get `Permission denied (publickey)` [on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20175441/432903)

`$ sudo ssh -i upd_prayag.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-209-155-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

They suggest `sudo su -` should work but it has been asking password, some of the links I found through google is making me anxious that I can't get root access.

### Reference

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 0):

If the instance is created from an AWS image, then you cannot get root access.