# Not able to connect to remote Amazon Instance via SSH (Permission denied(publickey))

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can anyone help me fix this issue, I am trying to access Amazon Instance via ssh from another amazon instance, but I am getting the following error-

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-27 jmeter-ec2-master]$ ssh -i "JmeterCloud-Updated.pem" ec2-user@ec2-52-38-189-49.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Permission denied (publickey).

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Publish more error message . There can be different error in between.

Comment: Check again whether you are using the correct privatekey associate with ec2-52-38-189-49 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied (publickey) when SSH Access to Amazon EC2 instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551556/permission-denied-publickey-when-ssh-access-to-amazon-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Did You Use the chmod command to make sure your private key file isn't publicly viewable. For example, if the name of your private key file is my-key-pair.pem, use the following command:

chmod 400 /path/my-key-pair.pem

Comment: the server cares about the permissions of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (and directory), the permission of the pem file on the client host is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
chmod 600 JmeterCloud-Updated.pem
```

to give adequate access to the key and then try to login into that instance.

Comment: the server cares about the permissions of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (and directory), the permission of the pem file on the client host is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Some ssh client will warn the user if private-key permission too open.