# AWS EC2 Bitnami Wordpress - Can't get username or password- access denied (public key)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, lamp, bitnami

I have installed the bitnami wordpress LAMP stack onto AWS EC2 instance free tier.
The wordpress site is up and working but I cannot get into wordpress admin.
I can't get the password or username for the site.

I have tried through ssh after downloading the PEM key and cd'ing to the pem key location, but I get the message: access denied (public key).

when i try to connect to the instance I get this message:

Run this command, if necessary, to ensure your key is not publicly viewable.
chmod 400 "example-name"

Connect to your instance using its Public DNS:

ec2-...,.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
ssh -i "keypair-name.pem" admin@ec2....eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com

I have removed the personal details from the above but followed the correct format

when I do this I get access denied (public key).
The solutions online seem not to work or are out of date.
I tried creating another key but that got the same result.

The other solution here does not seem relevant since I followed simple instructions:
[Permission denied (publickey) when SSH Access to Amazon EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551556/permission-denied-publickey-when-ssh-access-to-amazon-ec2-instance)

Comment: When you say "I have installed the bitnami wordpress LAMP stack", did you install it all yourself, or did you use a pre-existing AMI that already has it all loaded? If the latter, see: [Find application credentials](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/find-credentials/)

Comment: Thank you that works for the latter. When I tried that previously it didn't work. It works  now :).

Answer (score 0):

To obtain WordPress Admin credentials for a Bitnami instance, use the instructions found at [Find application credentials](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/find-credentials/):

- Use **Get System Log** in the EC2 management console (with the instance selected)
- Copy the password displayed
- Use it on the WordPress instance